# app.root.function unknown in kivy custom widget?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to learn Kivy and I can't figure why the add_key() function work with the Checkbox but not with the Spinner ?

I got : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_key' ?

Both custom widget's structure seems identical, the add_key function must be stored in the "MainWidget".
Curiously it work with the checkbox but not with the spinner ?!

Minimal code corresponding to my problem :

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

selection = {}

pizza = ["margarita", "vegetarian", "american", "3 cheeses"]

KV="""
<Selection@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    label_txt: ""
    key_name: ""
    Label:
        text: root.label_txt
    Spinner:
        id: spin_id
        text: ""
        on_text: app.root.add_key(root.key_name, self.text)

<Radio_op@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    op: ""
    label_op: ""
    Label:
        text: root.label_op
    CheckBox:
        group:"topping"
        on_active: app.root.add_key("topping", root.op)

<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Selection:
            id: pizza_sel
            label_txt: "pizza"
            key_name: "pizza"
        Label: 
            text: "Choose topping:"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            Radio_op:
                label_op:"cream"
                op: "cream"
            Radio_op:
                label_op:"cheese"
                op: "cheese"
            Radio_op:
                label_op:"tomatoes"
                op: "tomatoes"
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                id: pizza_lbl
            Label:
                id: topping_lbl
"""

class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.pizza_sel.ids.spin_id.text   = pizza[0]
        self.ids.pizza_sel.ids.spin_id.values = pizza

    def add_key(self, name, text):
        selection[name] = text
        #self.ids.pizza_lbl.text = selection["pizza"]
        self.ids.topping_lbl.text = selection["topping"]

Builder.load_string(KV)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()`
```

Error code :

```
   File "c:\Users\florian\Desktop\Local\Scripts python\Utilitaire de puissance V3\help.py", line 76, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\florian\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 954, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "C:\Users\florian\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 924, in _run_prepare
     root = self.build()
   File "c:\Users\florian\Desktop\Local\Scripts python\Utilitaire de puissance V3\help.py", line 73, in build
     return MainScreen()
   File "c:\Users\florian\Desktop\Local\Scripts python\Utilitaire de puissance V3\help.py", line 61, in __init__
     self.ids.pizza_sel.ids.spin_id.text   = pizza[0]
   File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 35, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 520, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 567, in kivy.properties.Property.set
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 606, in kivy.properties.Property._dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1307, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1189, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\Users\florian\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 55, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_key'
```

When I comment the Spinner on_text attribute, the checkbox is working fine :
[image]

Please, can anyone explain me why ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When MainScreen object is created app.root attribute is not yet set.
And because you are setting Spinner's text attribute within MainScreen constructor:

```
self.ids.pizza_sel.ids.spin_id.text   = pizza[0]
```

you are invoking Spinner's on_text event, before app.root is set, that's why you end up with exception. At this stage app.root is still set to None.

Do not set spin_id.text within constructor, instead of set it within KV definition.

```
#self.ids.pizza_sel.ids.spin_id.text   = pizza[0]

Spinner:
    id: spin_id
    text: "margarita"
```

You can also add pizza list as an MyApp class attribute:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        self.pizza = pizza
```

then you will be able to set Spinner text and values within KV definition like this:

```
Spinner:
    id: spin_id
    text: app.pizza[0]
    values: app.pizza
```

This way you can remove MainScreen constructor at all:

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    # def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    #     super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    #     self.ids.pizza_sel.ids.spin_id.values = pizza
    #     self.ids.pizza_sel.ids.spin_id.text   = pizza[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.

But the point to use a custom widget is to use the same spinner with other list. What if I want to replace the pizza list by let say that, an burger list ? [chicken, american, vegetarian...].
My aim is to have a KV file with :

```
BoxLayout:
    Selection:
     id: choose_pizza
     label_txt: "Choose a pizza"
     spin_values: app.pizza_list

    Selection:
     id: choose_burger
     label_txt: "Choose a burger"
     spin_values: app.burger_list
```

That's the simples example I have. But imagine if I got a long long list of meals (fries, drinks, etc...) and I want to avoid to copy/past the full custom widget ? Controlling "Selection" with only 3 argument ? (Label_txt, values), the initial spinner.text is always values[0] ?

Comment: Hi! Don't use answers to clarify your question. Use comments to answer or edit your question istead.